# DriveApp.getFolderById :No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it

Tags: google-app-maker

sorry. stuck again. I have a driveapp fileid and folderid. all correct i am sure about that. trying to just move fileid into the folderid (server-side script):

```
function moveFiles(sourceFileId, targetFolderId, role) {

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceFileId);   
  file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
  DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId).addFile(file);
  return "1";
    }
```

The line that crashes is the `DriveApp.getFolderById()` line, with the error message above (`No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it`)

these are files and folders that i own with my account. i cant see that it would be a permissions issue

Comment: Can you post more of your code, specifically the way you're calling this function and the way you're acquiring the file and folder Ids? I was able to run this function without any trouble.

Comment: Thanks App Maker Team. Your comment was helpful because it made me go and double check. I was actually passing the fileUrl not the fileId value... Now it's working great.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake...

I was using the `getUrl()` not the `getId()`... My bad